# jQuery Mobile unbind, remove or ignore the call to refresh when using data-role=none

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to ignore all calls to refresh (because they generate errors when I set data-role="none") in jQuery Mobile without removing the actual calls.

```
<div data-role="none">
    <label for="select-choice-1" class="select">Choose shipping method:</label>
    <select name="select-choice-1" id="select-choice-1" data-role="none">
        <option value="standard">Standard: 7 day</option>
        <option value="rush">Rush: 3 days</option>
        <option value="express">Express: next day</option>
        <option value="overnight">Overnight</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

The following call  generates an error in javascript (because the data-role="none").

```
$('#select-choice-1').selectmenu('refresh');
```

The error I receive is:

```
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on selectmenu prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'
```

This error does not exist if I remove data-role="none".

Is there a way to ignore/override the call to refresh? I have tried to use jQuery .unbind and .off but without success, example:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mypage", function( event ) {
    $('#select-choice-1').unbind('refresh');
});
```

I don't want to remove the calls to refresh in Javascript unless I have to because I want it to be easy to reapply the jQuery Mobile style at a later time. Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? a native selectmenu without jqm styles?

Comment: Yes no jqm styles but I would like to still be able to call 'refresh'. This is because the default behavior in the application is to have jqm styling but I would like to disable the style and apply another style in some situations.

Comment: if you want to ignore jQM styles, you wont need to use _refresh_ method. Because you disable `.selectmenu()` widget and thus you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if($('#select-choice-1').selectmenu()){
      $('#select-choice-1').selectmenu('refresh');
}
```

or

```
if($('#select-choice-1').data("role")!="none"){ 
         $('#select-choice-1').selectmenu('refresh');
}
```

You can't call a method of an object thant doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable `.selectmenu()` widget, you need to modify this globally on `mobileinit`. Moreover, there is no need to add `data-role="none"`.

This way, `select` tag won't be enhanced/styled with jQM and will be left untouched (*native look*).

If you do so, you aren't ought to use `.selectmenu("refresh")`, because the widget is disabled.

To tell jQM not to style `select` tag, bind global modifications to `mobileinit`, add them after jQuery and before jQuery Mobile JS libraries.

1. jQuery Mobile 1.3.2 and below

   ```
   <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
       $.mobile.page.prototype.options.keepNative = "select";
     });
   </script>
   <script src="jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/59uST/)**
2. jQuery Mobile 1.4

   ```
   <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
   <script>
     $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
       $.mobile.keepNative = "select";
     });
   </script>
   <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/vyUpd/)**